# Prolog- How to assign an expression to variable

Tags: string, prolog, expression, predicate

Hello i am trying to build an predicate which for given parameters return a whole new expression.
Let say i want to create new expression by adding both numbers.
So when I execute sth like this.

```
my_predicate(1,2,X).
```

Prolog would return:

```
X = 1+2
```

Unfortunately i dont know how can I build such a structure and assign it to `X` variable. I would be grateful for advice on this topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The predicate should describe a relation between potential arguments and expressions they could form, so why not call it args_expr/3. Here's an example for addition and multiplication. You can easily expand this approach for other expressions:

```
args_expr(Arg1,Arg2,Arg1 + Arg2).
args_expr(Arg1,Arg2,Arg1 * Arg2).
```

Example queries:

```
   ?- args_expr(1,2,X).
X = 1+2 ? ;
X = 1*2

   ?- args_expr((1+2),(3*4),X).
X = 1+2+3*4 ? ;
X = (1+2)*(3*4)

   ?- args_expr(1+2,3*4,X).
X = 1+2+3*4 ? ;
X = (1+2)*(3*4)
```

Comment: You don't even need the quotes around the operator. `args_expr(A, B, A+B).` would suffice.

Comment: what about parantheses? for instace: X = (1+2)

Comment: @Dago you just need to decide what you want. Are you wanting `X` to be a Prolog term`1+2` which is equivalent to the term`(1+2)` since the outer parentheses are superfluous in this context, or do you want the atom, `'(1+2)'`? As a term, the parentheses are unnecessary unless the term is more complex. For example, `args_expr(A,B,C,A+(B+C)).` being called with, `args_expr(1,2,3,X)` would yield, `X=1+(2+3)`.

Comment: @lurker: You are absolutely right. I edited my code accordinngly :-)

Comment: @Dago: I added 2 example queries to illustrate lurkers point about paratheses

Comment: i want to have paranthesses for multiplication. So for given A and B, which can be more complex.  So for instance. X = ((1+2)*(1+3))*2

Comment: @Dago: The outermost parentheses in `((1+2)*(1+3))*2` are unnecessary since `(A*B)*C=A*(B*C)`, so prolog removes them. If you want unnecessary parentheses anyway you can consider using  atoms instead of terms as @lurker suggested. For example in SWI-Prolog, you can use term_to_atom/2 to convert an expression into an atom and atom_concat/2 to add '(' at the beginning and ')' at the end. But be aware that `'(1*1)'` does not unify with `1*1`. And if you convert the atom back to a term with atom_to_term/3, the unnecessary parentheses are gone again.

Comment: Hi, I want something similar but not with arithmetics... for example, I want that for args_expr(1,2,X). => X=Y(1,2). I was unable to copy the same Idea. Help will be great

Comment: @Tomer: You could do so using =../2. Consider having some facts functor/1, describing all available functors, e.g. `functor(f).`, `functor(g).` and so on. Then you could define a predicate `args_struct(A,S) :- functor(F), S =.. [F|A].`. Querying this predicate `?- args_struct([a,b],S).` yields `S = f(a, b)` and `S = g(a, b)`. Note that the first argument is a list, hence you can describe structures of arbitrary arity. And the predicate also works in the other direction, e.g. `?- args_struct(A,f(a,b)).` yields `A = [a, b]`. But the basic idea is still the same as above.

Comment: Hi, I checked this but I get "Undefined procedure: functor/1"  So I tried "args_struct(A,[F|A]) :- functor(F,X,Y), S =..[F|A]." but this resulted in: "functor/3: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated". but thanks!

Comment: @Tomer: Read  the comment again. The suggested code consists of three lines. Line 1: `functor(f).` Line 2: `functor(g).` Line 3: `args_struct(A,S) :- functor(F), S =.. [F|A].` According to the 1st error message you didn't include the two facts functor/1 (lines 1 and 2). When Prolog reported this you tried to fix it by replacing functor/1 with the built-in functor/3, which a) does something completely different and b) requires the first argument to be sufficiently instantiated (2nd error message). If you want args_struct/2 to work you need to __exactly__ copy the __entire__ code.

Comment: My bad! Yes I misunderstood. I tried to replace to functor/3 since this is a built in function. Thanks now I can start to understand what you wrote

Comment: Sorry for the bother, but how about if I don't know all available functors? will assert help? (Ofcourse your right about voting I always try to remember that, for some reason I forgot)

Comment: @Tomer: The entire point of the goal `functor(F)` being first is to make sure that the first argument of univ (=../2) is __not__ variable but an atom in order to avoid an instantiation error. Try the following queries to see this: `?- X =.. [Y,Z].` and `?- X =.. [y,Z].`. So you have to know all functors that are relevant to your application or you have to make do with the ones you know at the time. Alternatively you could make the predicate functor/1 dynamic and use assertz/1 and retract/1 to add/remove facts at runtime. See the SWI-documentation on those predicates for details and examples.